# Selenium 2 :- selenium.isTextPresent fails assertion in IE8 while it passes in Chrome or firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I am trying to check for the string "Education + Add a school" for Linked profile (Under Profile -Edit Profile) in Selenium Junit 4 test case with following command:

assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Education + Add a school"));

When I view the webpage source,the stirng appears in  :

### Education
              + **Add** a school

The assertTrue returns True or passes validation as expected in chrome.However in I.E 8 I get
assertionFailedError.I am using windows 7 and Selenium 2.21.0 .

I am not sure why the behaviour is different on different browser.

The code looks like :

public class test12 extends SeleneseTestCase {

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "https://www.linkedin.com/");
    selenium.start();
    }

@Test
public void testTest12() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/uas/login?goback=&trk=hb_signin");
    selenium.type("id=session_key-login", "xxxxx");
    selenium.type("id=session_password-login", "xxxxxx");
    selenium.click("id=btn-primary");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

    selenium.click("link=Edit Profile");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

    assertEquals("Improve your Profile", selenium.getText("css=a  [name=\"guidedEdit\"] > span"));
    assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("id=yui-gen8"));

    //the below assertion failes in I.E 8,but it runs fine in chrome
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Education + Add a school"));

    assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("css=#yui-gen7 > span.edit"));
    assertEquals("Edit Profile | Linked", selenium.getTitle());

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    selenium.stop();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to your IE8 settings.

When running selenium in IE you should change your Security Options under Internet Options to all have 'Enable Protected Mode' either all checked, or all unchecked (for Internet, Local, Trusted and Restricted). Another setting that can interfere is Compatibility Mode. Push F12 in an IE8 browser when running the test and look at the Browser and Document modes. If either of these say compatibility mode, you should find the Compatibility Mode settings and turn it off.

If you can't find any of these settings let me know and I can screenshot it for you (though I am running IE9) and also please say if it doesn't work, because I would be interested to know the solution then! :)

EDIT:

Solved by accessing the element and checking the text from the element. Using code:

```
 String checkForEducation = selenium.getText("id=yui-gen10"); 
 assertEquals("Education + Add a school", checkForEducation);
```

Comment: Hi Nashibukasan,thanks for the suggestion.The IE 8 settings for security are turned off(it gives another error when turnned on).With resepect to the compatibility as sugested I checked the Brower Mode(it says IE8 in drop down) and Document mode (IE 8 Standards).I did this by pressing f12 when the test case was triggered from eclipse.It still does not work.

Comment: That's a pity. Have you tried getting the text directly from an element opposed to using a 'isTextPresent' call? it is possible this is timing out before it finds your text on the page? So, try get the element that should contain the text and assert whether the 'text' field of the element contains "Education + Add a school".

Comment: Thanks for the help .I tried this and was able to verify it.Is this the right approach ? String checkForEducation = selenium.getText("id=yui-gen10"); assertEquals("Education + Add a school", selenium.getText("id=yui-gen10")); System.out.println(checkForEducation);

Comment: Yes, did that work? Though you don't need to call 'getText' the second time, just use your string. So; String checkForEducation = selenium.getText("id=yui-gen10"); assertEquals("Education + Add a school", checkForEducation); Though, I am not sure how your assert works as I am use to WebDriver.

Comment: No problem, I have updated the answer so that it reflects the actual solution so that it can help others in the future.

Comment: Is it possible that the 'isTextPresent' method will only look through to a certain level? (Eg. <div><div><div>stop) I am not sure, though I have found in general it is safer (if possible) to check the element directly.